# Best way to create colored text boxes

Tags: color, boxes

I am retyping some old exams into LaTeX, and I encountered the page below

[image: Old exam]

Now with some clever commands, and whatnot I was able to create something almost identical. Though the spacing is a tad off, and my equation is a tad small. I also had to use some hacks and ugly code to produce the result

Does anyone have a better cleaner way to do this ?

Here is almost the exact code I am using for typesetting these exams. Only difference is that all the "junk" in the header is placed i sty. files. So y header contains only 3-5 input files. Here I included everything that is needed to run the code. Some improvements to the code below would be great.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{tittel}
\setcounter{tittel}{0}
\newcounter{problem}
\setcounter{problem}{0}
\newcounter{alternative}
\setcounter{alternative}{0}

\newcounter{navn}[problem]
\renewcommand{\thenavn}{\alph{navn}}
\newcommand{\navn}{\stepcounter{navn}\paragraph*{\thenavn)}}
\setcounter{navn}{0}

\newcommand{\NR}[1]
{ \vspace{5mm} \begin{minipage}[t]{0.051 \textwidth}
 \navn \hspace{0pt}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.949\textwidth}
#1 
\end{minipage}
\vspace{-0.3cm}
}

\newif\iffirstalt

\NewDocumentCommand{\Oppgave}{m o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\setcounter{alternative}{0}\stepcounter{problem}    \firstaltfalse}%
              {\stepcounter{alternative}\iffirstalt\else\stepcounter{problem}    \firstalttrue\fi}
  \section*{Oppgave \arabic{problem}%
             {\normalfont\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{~Alternative     \Roman{alternative}\ }
                \normalsize (#1 poeng)}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Oppgave \arabic{problem} }} 
\vspace{3mm} }

\begin{document}

\Oppgave{5}

En gruppe på $8$ elever besår av like mange gutter som jenter. Vi trekker     tilfeldig ut 8 elever.

\NR{ Hva er sannsynligheten for å trekke ut $2$ gutter og $1$ jente? }

\NR{ Hva er sannsynligheten for å trekke ut minst $1$ jente? }

\begin{center}

  \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{LightSteelBlue}{%
    \parbox[t][3cm][c]{11cm}{ \hspace*{0.25cm} Hypergeometrisk     sannsynlighetsfordeling: $\displaystyle P(X=x)=\dfrac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{r-k}}{\binom{n}{r}}$ \\ 
    \hspace*{0.25cm} $m$ elementer i $D$. $n-m$ elementer i $\bar{D}$ \\
   \hspace*{0.25cm} $r$ elementer trekkes tilfeldig. \\
   \hspace*{0.25cm} $X$ er antall elementer som trekkes fra $D$  }%
  }%
   \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

Below is a minimal example, barely enough to produce the page above.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\section*{Oppgave 2 \normalsize \normalfont (5 poeng)}

En gruppe på $8$ elever besår av like mange gutter som jenter. Vi trekker     tilfeldig ut 8 elever.

\paragraph*{a)} Hva er sannsynligheten for å trekke ut $2$ gutter og $1$ jente? 

\paragraph*{b)} Hva er sannsynligheten for å trekke ut minst $1$ jente? 

\begin{center}

  \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{LightSteelBlue}{%
    \parbox[t][3cm][c]{11cm}{ \hspace*{0.25cm} Hypergeometrisk     sannsynlighetsfordeling: $\displaystyle P(X=x)=\dfrac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{r-k}}{\binom{n}{r}}$ \\ 
    \hspace*{0.25cm} $m$ elementer i $D$. $n-m$ elementer i $\bar{D}$ \\
   \hspace*{0.25cm} $r$ elementer trekkes tilfeldig. \\
   \hspace*{0.25cm} $X$ er antall elementer som trekkes fra $D$  }%
  }%
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Here is how my output looks

[image: My output]

Question(s)

- Is there an easier way, that also looks better for creating the blue box?
- Are there any smal improvements that could be done to my "long" code?

Comment: Yesterday I uploaded mdframed v1.0. There is an example which produces your output.

Comment: You mention that your formula was a bit small: to fix that use `\dbinom` instead of `\binom`.  This needs `amsmath` which is already included by `mathtools'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here a way to define such a box using `adjustbox`. See the manual for more options.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcounter{tittel}
\setcounter{tittel}{0}
\newcounter{problem}
\setcounter{problem}{0}
\newcounter{alternative}
\setcounter{alternative}{0}

\newcounter{navn}[problem]
\renewcommand{\thenavn}{\alph{navn}}
\newcommand{\navn}{\stepcounter{navn}\paragraph*{\thenavn)}}
\setcounter{navn}{0}

\newcommand{\NR}[1]
{ \vspace{5mm} \begin{minipage}[t]{0.051 \textwidth}
 \navn \hspace{0pt}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.949\textwidth}
#1 
\end{minipage}
\vspace{-0.3cm}
}

\newif\iffirstalt

\NewDocumentCommand{\Oppgave}{m o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\setcounter{alternative}{0}\stepcounter{problem}    \firstaltfalse}%
              {\stepcounter{alternative}\iffirstalt\else\stepcounter{problem}    \firstalttrue\fi}
  \section*{Oppgave \arabic{problem}%
             {\normalfont\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{~Alternative     \Roman{alternative}\ }
                \normalsize (#1 poeng)}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Oppgave \arabic{problem} }} 
\vspace{3mm} }

\newenvironment{bluebox}{%
    \noindent
    \adjustbox{innerenv={varwidth}[c]{0.9\linewidth},margin=\fboxsep+.25cm \fboxsep+.2cm,bgcolor=LightSteelBlue,frame,center}\bgroup
}{%
    \egroup
}

\begin{document}

\Oppgave{5}

En gruppe på $8$ elever besår av like mange gutter som jenter. Vi trekker     tilfeldig ut 8 elever.

\NR{ Hva er sannsynligheten for å trekke ut $2$ gutter og $1$ jente? }

\NR{ Hva er sannsynligheten for å trekke ut minst $1$ jente? }


\begin{bluebox}
   Hypergeometrisk     sannsynlighetsfordeling: $\displaystyle P(X=x)=\dfrac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{r-k}}{\binom{n}{r}}$ \\
   $m$ elementer i $D$. $n-m$ elementer i $\bar{D}$ \\
   $r$ elementer trekkes tilfeldig. \\
   $X$ er antall elementer som trekkes fra $D$
\end{bluebox}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: It seems as both of these solutions deppends on that I know how wide and tall the box is supposed to be. Is there any way to adjust the height and width of the box automaticaly? Thanks a lot for your answer =)

Comment: Yes, use the `varwidth` environment from the package with the same name. I actually just now release a new version of `adjustbox` which has a `varwidth` key, but you can use it without it as well.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: See my updated answer. The `varwidth` environment takes a maximal width argument, but uses the normal width of the content.

Comment: Really cool. Thanks a bunch! Will look into that package. Does this also change the height of the box? I am not too conserned about page breaks. As these boxes will always range from half a page to a sentence.

Comment: `varwidth` accepts the same arguments like `minipage` or `\parbox`, so you can also give an optional height argument. However, if you simply want to add some height, i.e. vertical padding, I would use the `margin` key of `adjustbox`, which can also be used multiple times.

Comment: I might also want to add `\par\medskip` above and below to get some vertical separation, or add the `margin=0pt \medskipamount` key at the very end.

Answer (score 7):

Here a solution with `mdframed`. Other possibilities are the packages `adjustbox` or you simple use `tikz` (no page breaks available).

The new version is uploaded to CTAN. If you want to test the current example the package can be downloaded [here](http://www.mada-nada.de/downloads/mdframed.zip) (include also the new documentations)

According to your numbering of paragraphs I would create a new command which does it for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{NR}{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip,%
                    ,align=center,%
                    innerleftmargin=.25cm,linecolor=black,%
                    linewidth=2pt,backgroundcolor=LightSteelBlue}
\newmdenv[style=NR]{NR}

\newcounter{myparagraph}
\setcounter{myparagraph}{0}
\newcommand\myparagraph[1]{\stepcounter{myparagraph}\paragraph*{\alph{myparagraph})\quad#1}}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\myparagraph{Hva er sannsynligheten for å trekke ut $2$ gutter og $1$ jente?}

\myparagraph{Hva er sannsynligheten for å trekke ut minst $1$ jente?}
\begin{NR}[userdefinedwidth=11cm]
Hypergeometrisk     sannsynlighetsfordeling: $\displaystyle P(X=x)=\dfrac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{r-k}}{\binom{n}{r}}$ \\ 
$m$ elementer i $D$. $n-m$ elementer i $\bar{D}$ \\
$r$ elementer trekkes tilfeldig. \\
$X$ er antall elementer som trekkes fra $D$
\end{NR}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems as both of these solutions deppends on that I know how wide and tall the box is supposed to be. Is there any way to adjust the height and width of the box automaticaly? Thanks a lot for your answer =)

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `varwidth` and `tcolorbox`, which is there almost out of the box, defining a special `bluebox` macro:

This declares the `\bluebox` macro having one optional and one mandatory argument, with blue background, center alignment with respect to page and using at most `0.8\linewidth` as width and having no frame.

Other options can be given with the optional argument, see the `yellow` background for the `bluebox` ;-)

```
\newtcbox{bluebox}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw, 
      sharp corners,
      colback=LightSteelBlue,
      center,
      varwidth upper=0.8\linewidth,
      frame hidden,
      #1}
```

Full code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcbox{bluebox}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw, 
  sharp corners,
  colback=LightSteelBlue,
  center,
  varwidth upper=0.8\linewidth,
  frame hidden,
  #1}

\begin{document}

\section*{Oppgave 2 \normalsize \normalfont (5 poeng)}

En gruppe på $8$ elever besår av like mange gutter som jenter. Vi trekker     tilfeldig ut 8 elever.

\paragraph*{a)} Hva er sannsynligheten for å trekke ut $2$ gutter og $1$ jente? 

\paragraph*{b)} Hva er sannsynligheten for å trekke ut minst $1$ jente? 


\bluebox{%
  Hypergeometrisk sannsynlighetsfordeling: $\displaystyle P(X=x)=\dfrac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{r-k}}{\binom{n}{r}}$

 $m$ elementer i $D$. $n-m$ elementer i $\bar{D}$ \\
 $r$ elementer trekkes tilfeldig. \\
 $X$ er antall elementer som trekkes fra $D$  %
}

\bluebox[colback=yellow!60!white]{%
  Hypergeometrisk sannsynlighetsfordeling: $\displaystyle P(X=x)=\dfrac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{r-k}}{\binom{n}{r}}$

 $m$ elementer i $D$. $n-m$ elementer i $\bar{D}$ \\
 $r$ elementer trekkes tilfeldig. \\
 $X$ er antall elementer som trekkes fra $D$  %
}



\begin{center}

  \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{LightSteelBlue}{%
    \parbox[t][3cm][c]{11cm}{ \hspace*{0.25cm} Hypergeometrisk     sannsynlighetsfordeling: $\displaystyle P(X=x)=\dfrac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{r-k}}{\binom{n}{r}}$ \\ 
    \hspace*{0.25cm} $m$ elementer i $D$. $n-m$ elementer i $\bar{D}$ \\
   \hspace*{0.25cm} $r$ elementer trekkes tilfeldig. \\
   \hspace*{0.25cm} $X$ er antall elementer som trekkes fra $D$  }%
  }%
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\newenvironment{bluebox}
  {\begin{lrbox}{0}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}}
  {\end{tabular}\end{lrbox}%
   \setlength{\fboxsep}{12pt}% adjust at will
  {\centering\fcolorbox{black}{LightSteelBlue}{\usebox{0}}\par}}
```