# Fill vertical space in a beamerposter poster

Tags: posters, beamerposter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does vfill not work inside a beamer column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15244/why-does-vfill-not-work-inside-a-beamer-column)

I'm trying to tweak beamerposter examples to my needs. The one example I found fairly simply as a starting point on the one hand and full enough on the other can be found at [Shawn Lankton Online](http://www.shawnlankton.com/?s=beamer).

However, I fill to achieve one thing, namely fill vertical space, when the boxes are "too" small. For instance, in the example poster, given in the zip file, the boxes are rather small, and concentrated at the center of the page. *How can they be spread vertical and evenly over the page?*

I tried using `\vfill` but it didn't work... Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[serif,mathserif,final]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=70,height=40,scale=.6,debug]{beamerposter}

\begin{frame}{}
  \begin{columns}[t]

    \begin{column}{0.32\linewidth}
      \begin{block}{Summary}
        Block 1
      \end{block}
\vfill
      \begin{block}{Motivation}
        Block 2
      \end{block}
\vfill
      \begin{block}{Columns}
        Block 3
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I wouldn't say a 100% duplicate, but strongly related. Actually, Martin's answer in the linked question solved my problem.

Comment: As TorbjørnT. suggested, [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15244/why-does-vfill-not-work-inside-a-beamer-column/15248#15248) of Martin, actually provides a solution to my problem. The root is the way `columns` internally works, and the work around based on the usage of `vbox`.

Comment: I added an answer with a reference to Martin's answer. I think it it better to keep this question open as well, as it specifies on the `beamerposter` package.

Comment: @Dror As you seem happy with the solution in the linked question, I feel this should be closed as a duplicate. This question will remain about as a 'marker' when searching, which is the usual approach on TeX.sx.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to accomplish this.

One of the easiest solutions is add a rubber length. This is done by inlcuding the code

\hspace*{ 5cm } for example. This adds 5cm vertical space.

Another way to accomplish this is by using the package 'varwidth'

[Best way to create colored text boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/best-way-to-create-colored-text-boxes)

Comment: `hspace` adds horizontal space ;-)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: This indeed produces bigger space between the boxes, but it won't spread them evenly along (vertically) the page. I see that I have to clarify the question itself...

Comment: A minimal example of what you want would be great

Comment: In the link I sent you can find the files I'm considering - I don't know how to turn them into MWE... I'm trying to have the block evenly and vertically distributed along the page.

Comment: @Dror You basically strip away everything that doesn't matter, while still having compilable code that demonstrates the problem. I added one to your post, hope that's OK. Did you look at the question I linked to in my comment above?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. : Your MWE is indeed related, but I wasn't sure whether the problem is related to definitions in auxiliary files, therefore I linked to the whole package I was considering.